# Oracle BI Publisher - Reporting by Upcoming Expiration Date

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

I am trying to integrate a script in my query that will return rows that are only due to expire within the next 30days in from the END_DATE column.  Here is my query:

```
select   "SITE"."NAME" as "NAME",
     "CONTRACT_TYPE"."NAME" as "NAME_1",
     "CONTRACT"."END_DATE" as "END_DATE" 
 from   "DB"."SITE" "SITE",
    "DB"."CONTRACT" "CONTRACT",
    "DB"."CONTRACT_TYPE" "CONTRACT_TYPE" 
 where   "CONTRACT"."CONTRACT_TYPE_ID"="CONTRACT_TYPE"."ID"
 and     "CONTRACT"."SITE_ID"="SITE"."ID";
```

Here is the current output:

```
NAME          NAME_1        END_DATE
----------    --------      ----------
Customer_1    Contract      11-NOV-17
Customer_2    Contract      13-OCT-17
Customer_3    Contract      02-DEC-17
Customer_4    Contract      15-JAN-18
```

I would like to only show the END_DATE that will be expiring within 30days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
select   "SITE"."NAME" as "NAME",
     "CONTRACT_TYPE"."NAME" as "NAME_1",
     "CONTRACT"."END_DATE" as "END_DATE" 
 from   "DB"."SITE" "SITE",
    "DB"."CONTRACT" "CONTRACT",
    "DB"."CONTRACT_TYPE" "CONTRACT_TYPE" 
 where   "CONTRACT"."CONTRACT_TYPE_ID"="CONTRACT_TYPE"."ID"
 and     "CONTRACT"."SITE_ID"="SITE"."ID"
and "CONTRACT"."END_DATE" <= sysdate + 30;
```